# Automation Anywhere Citrix Plugin

Tags: automation, citrix, automationanywhere

From a developer's perspective:

- What technologies and algorithms are used to model the application?
- How does the plugin overcome the inaccessibility of the application's UI object model?
- What are the limitations of the plugin vs. what a normal user can do with Citrix?